# Add sortable to extendable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Dear StackOverflow users,

I am looking for a solution for this problem for 3 days now and I cant find it on the internet. My job is to make an Admin-panel to add invoices. What I have so far is a table which is extendable when you click on the row and my goal is to make it sortable.

```js
$(function() {
    $("tr.child-row").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-poducts">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    verbergen
                </th>
                <th>
                    Aantal
                </th>
                <th>
                    Verwijzing
                </th>
                <th>
                    Beschrijving
                </th>
                <th>
                    Angeboden prijs
                </th>
                <th>
                    Korting
                </th>
                <th>
                    Nieuwe prijs
                </th>
                <th>
                    Totaal
                </th>
                <th>
                    Acties
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hide[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td>
                    31516
                </td>
                <td>
                    DIGIDOT LED STRIP RGB HR 5m 24V BLACK PCB
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    €285,00
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    50%
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    €142,50
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    €142,50
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="btn">Click me</button>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="child-row">
                <td colspan="9">
                    <div id="test">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50%">
                                    <textarea></textarea>
                                </td>
                                <td width="50%">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">kleine text</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hide[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td>
                    31516
                </td>
                <td>
                    DIGIDOT LED STRIP RGB HR 5m 24V BLACK PCB
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    €285,00
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    50%
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    €142,50
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    €142,50
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="btn">Click me</button>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="child-row">
                <td colspan="9">
                    <div id="test">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50%">
                                    <textarea></textarea>
                                </td>
                                <td width="50%">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">kleine text</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I mean by making it sortable is that you can drag and drop it And reorder it somewhere else in the table.

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: While a JSFiddle can be helpful, it is good practice to include your code (only the relevant parts) in your SO post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the Start and stop function in sortable and define a start position and end position and from there you can Clone the child row.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty wrong with your HTML code. Please review it. You can make use of [jQueryUI library's sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to sort them easily.

```js
 
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
   items: "tr",

    });
    $( "#sortable tr" ).disableSelection();
```

```css
#sortable tr{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div  id="sortable">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>verbergen</th>
    <th>Aantal  </th>
    <th>Verwijzing</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="hide[]"/></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="hide[]"/></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="hide[]"/></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>C </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="hide[]"/></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>D </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="hide[]"/></td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="hide[]"/></td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>F </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your fast response, I have read the JQueryUI Documentation but i cant figure it out how drag and drop 2 rows (Parrent row + child row).

Comment: You can sort the rows in the posted snippet . I hope you will find this answer useful.

Comment: I think you understand me wrong, the idea is to drag and drop 2 rows at the sametime.

Comment: Do you mean to move the selected items at the same time and sort among other unselected?